# what is the best way to store local values in browser using Javascript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am storing local variables in Array. But when i try to refresh the page the array gets empty. I want previous values after page refres also.

I am trying "Previous/Next" functionality in Javascript. It is working fine .But when i try to reload the page the values in array get deleted.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script>
        var urllist = [];
        var ind = 0;
        var myVar;
        myVar = setInterval(Geturlfun, 3000);
        function Geturlfun() {
            var pageURL = window.location.href;
            if (urllist[ind - 1] == pageURL) {

            } else {
                urllist[ind] = pageURL;
                ind = ind + 1;
                alert(pageURL);
            }
        }
        function goBkHist(a) {
            var l_ref = ind - 2;
            if (l_ref != 0) {
                var pageURL2 = urllist[l_ref];
                ind = l_ref + 1;
                alert(pageURL2);
                loadUrl(pageURL2);
            }
        }
        function goFdHist(a) {
            var l_ref_2 = ind;
            var pageURL2 = urllist[l_ref_2];
            ind = l_ref_2 + 1;
            alert(pageURL2);
            loadUrl(pageURL2);
        }
        function loadUrl(newLocation) {
            window.location = newLocation;
            location.reload();
            return true;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="BACK " onclick="goBkHist(-1)" />
    <input type="button" value="FORWARD" onclick="goFdHist(1)" />
</body>
</html>
```

In this code if i click on Back or Forward the URL displayed but when i try to load that URL it page getting reloaded and values in array deleted.

How can i handle those issues.

Is there any way to handle this type of storing with other methods like Sessions and cookies.

Comment: So you're looking for some kind of... local storage?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Either use Cookies or LocalStorage.

Comment: Which variable do you want to maintain even after page refreshes ?

Comment: i want to maintain "ind"value and "urllist"array value after page refresh also.But it is not happen the array gets empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value stored in *[sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)* will be auto removed when you will close that tab.

If you store value in *[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)* will not be auto removed unless you delete it programmatically or delete browser data.

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <script>
                // Getting value from browser side.
                if (window.sessionStorage.getItem('url_list'))
                {
                    var urllist = $.parseJSON(window.sessionStorage.getItem('url_list'));
                }
                else
                {
                    var urllist = [];
                }
                var ind = 0;
                var myVar;
                myVar = setInterval(Geturlfun, 3000);
                function Geturlfun() {
                    var pageURL = window.location.href;
                    if (urllist[ind - 1] == pageURL)
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        urllist[ind] = pageURL;
                        ind = ind + 1;
                        alert(pageURL);
                    }
                    // Storing at browser side
                    window.sessionStorage.setItem('url_list', JSON.stringify(urllist))
                }
                function goBkHist(a) {
                    var l_ref = ind - 2;
                    if (l_ref != 0)
                    {
                        var pageURL2 = urllist[l_ref];
                        ind = l_ref + 1;
                        alert(pageURL2);
                        loadUrl(pageURL2);
                    }
                }
                function goFdHist(a) {
                    var l_ref_2 = ind;
                    var pageURL2 = urllist[l_ref_2];
                    ind = l_ref_2 + 1;
                    alert(pageURL2);
                    loadUrl(pageURL2);
                }
                function loadUrl(newLocation) {
                    window.location = newLocation;
                    location.reload();
                    return true;
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <input type="button" value="BACK " onclick="goBkHist(-1)" />
            <input type="button" value="FORWARD" onclick="goFdHist(1)" />
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ali Khanusiya,

Comment: My main goal is to store URLs into array every 3seconds.
Storings URLs working fine but when the page gets refresh the index[ind] and array[urllist] become null. i want to change the ind ,urllist length before refresh.Please tell me the final solution for this.

Comment: <script>
            var urllist = [];
            var ind = 0;
            var myVar;
            myVar = setInterval(Geturlfun, 3000);
            function Geturlfun() {
                var pageURL = window.location.href;
                if (urllist[ind - 1] == pageURL) {

                } else {
                    urllist[ind] = pageURL;                    
                    ind = ind + 1;
                    alert(pageURL);
                }
            }    
        </script>

Comment: This should work. Are you facing any issue in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LocalStorage API for persisting data at the client-side. If you have to support ancient browsers, you can write a simple fallback to cookies. Note that LocalStorage has some size limit, something about 10MB per domain if I remember correctly.

Check the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage).

You can simply use the `localStorage.getItem` and `localStorage.setItem` functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` 
By localStorage you can do this like

```
localStorage.setItem("DataValue", "Your Value");
```

and retrieve this by

```
localStorage.getItem("DataValue")
```

by sessionStorage its like

```
sessionStorage.DataValue = "Your Value"
```

and retrieve by

```
var Data = sessionStorage.DataValue
```

all of these are client side features. `sessionStorage` is bind with an individual tab of the browser where as the `localStorage` will be available throughout the browser.